# What dataset was Stanford NER trained on?

Tags: nlp, dataset, stanford-nlp

I would like to re-train the [Stanford NER library](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.html) from scratch as a 1 class model.

Only 3,4 and 7 class models are available out of the box.

Is it possible to obtain the data that the model was originally trained on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [original paper](https://nlp.stanford.edu/~manning/papers/gibbscrf3.pdf) mentions two corpora: CoNLL 2003 ([apparently here now](https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/conll2003/ner/)) and the "CMU Seminar Announcements Task". However according to the page linked in the question the actual NER was trained on a larger combination of corpora:

> Our big English NER models were trained on a mixture of CoNLL, MUC-6, MUC-7 and ACE named entity corpora, and as a result the models are fairly robust across domains.

So it might be difficult to obtain the *exact* original training data. However most of these corpora were compiled for some shared tasks and should be available online. There are probably more recent ones as well: a quick search "named entity recognition shared task" returns many hits.